# Issue in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 databases (v1, v7) with the same data structure and schema. Data on v7 larger than v1. When I run the the same SQL statement on v7 takes less than 1s
v1 also took over 11s.

My SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    bs.[ID], bs.[TapeID], bs.[ChanelID], bs.[ContractID],
    bs.[ContractSectionID], bs.[Name], bs.[RegisterDate],
    bs.[ValidFrom], bs.[ValidToDate], bs.[GPRP], bs.[Status],
    bs.[Note], bs.[Code], bs.[JobCodeID], bs.[SpotCount],
    bs.[BookNumber], bs.[Adjusted], bs.[PrintedCNPS],
    bs.[UserID], bs.[CreateTime], bs.[ModifiedTime],
    '' + t.Code + ' - ' + t.Name, ch.Code, 
    '[' + c.Code + '] ' + cus.Name, cs.Code, 
    jb.Code, p.Name, us.UserName, cus.Code, t.Duration,
    (select count(*) from Spot 
     where Position in ('1','2','3','E','D','F') 
       and bs.ID = Spot.BookScheudlerID 
       and Status not in (2,3,5)) as SpotUuTien, --mục địch tạo ra column
    (select count(*) from Spot 
     where Position in ('A') and Pending = 1 
       and bs.ID = Spot.BookScheudlerID 
       and Status not in (2, 3, 5)) as SpotUuTienFree, /*mục địch tạo ra column*/ 
FROM 
    [BookScheduler] bs 
INNER JOIN
    Tape t on bs.TapeID = t.ID
INNER JOIN
    Contract c on bs.ContractID = c.ID
INNER JOIN
    ContractSection cs on bs.ContractSectionID = cs.ID
LEFT JOIN 
    JobCode jb on bs.JobCodeID = jb.ID
INNER JOIN
    Product p on t.ProductID = p.ID
INNER JOIN
    Chanel ch on bs.ChanelID = ch.ID
INNER JOIN
    Customer cus on c.CustomerID = cus.ID
LEFT JOIN 
    AppUser us on bs.UserID = us.ID 
WHERE 
    bs.ValidFrom >= '05/01/2015 00:00:00' 
    AND bs.ValidToDate <= '05/30/2015 00:00:00'
```

I think the problem index on v1 should I rebuild its index. Then run the sql statement above, but the results did not change.

Then I created a new database have the same structured with v1 and I moved data from v1 to the new database, when I run the SQL statement on the new database very fast speed (like on v7).

So let me ask my v1 being what? and how to improve the speed to it without creating a new database?

Comment: What database server are you using?

Comment: I using sql server 2012

Comment: Are the execution plans identical?

Comment: I try create a new database same structure schema, no relationship and a new database same structure relationship, schema. But the results of both very fast speed.

Comment: As already suggested: compare the query plans (press CTRL-L). Are these databases on the same server? If the plans are the same, take a look at waits on the server. (I like to use `sp_WhoIsActive`, a third party sp)